# Laravel 5 - Allow to pass only FormRequest rules fields

Tags: laravel-5

I would like to use FormRequest validation in which 
allow request fields only in rules() return array keys.

In the below code, I would like to allow request fields only 'os', 'number', 'version'. If request include the other field , return error response.

How can I modify the code ?

```
public function rules()
  {
    return [
        'os' => [
            'required',
            \Rule::in(['android', 'ios']),
        ],
        'number' => 'required|integer',
        'version' => ['required', 'regex:/^\d+.\d+.\d+$/'],
    ];
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way you can do this using form request. It may not send the proper response but it works.
In your Form Request's authorize method use the following code.

```
public function authorize ()
{
    $params = $this->request->keys();
    $os_status = in_array('os', $params);
    $number_status = in_array('number', $params);
    $version_status = in_array('version', $params);

    $check = $os_status & $number_status & $version_status & (count($params) != 3 ? false : true);

    return $check;
}
```

It will return `HTTP` response with 403 status code.